# Cross-referencing not working with \tag and \label together

Tags: hyperref, labels, tag, eqref

I wrote two equations, both having labels and tags so that I can display them in my format as well as reference them later. However, while clicking on (1.1) or (1.2), both lead to the Equation (1.1). Somehow, 1.2 is not getting referenced properly. Here's a simplified version of the entire code, which contains the bug. I put the extra lines to easily discern here the difference between both references.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

    
        \begin{equation} \tag*{1.1} \label{1.1}
            a + b + c = d
        \end{equation}
        \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
        \begin{equation} \tag*{1.2} \label{1.2}
            e + f + g = h
        \end{equation}
    
    This is \ref{1.1}
    This is \ref{1.2}
    
\end{document}
```

This is the pdf output. While either clicking or hovering on either of the references, both lead to Equation a + b + c = d.
[image]

Comment: It does not work even by replacing ```\tag*``` with ```\tag```

Comment: Load [`hyperref`](//ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) *last*. See [Which packages should be loaded after `hyperref` instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1863/5764)

Comment: Thanks @Werner that worked for me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is solved by comment.

Comment: @Werner for amsmath the package order no longer matters in a current tex system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a current TeX system with a current hyperref your example should work. I removed the dependency on the package order for amsmath. In older systems you need to load amsmath as mentioned in a comment first.

If you use a `\tag` you should use better use the unnumbered `equation*` environment to avoid spurious warnings in the log about

```
pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{equation.0.1}) has been already used
```

They do not harm in your example, but indicate wrong links if you later use an `equation` without a tag.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}

    
        \begin{equation*} \tag*{1.1} \label{1.1}
            a + b + c = d
        \end{equation*}
        \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
        \begin{equation*} \tag*{1.2} \label{1.2}
            e + f + g = h
        \end{equation*}
    
        \begin{equation}  \label{next}
            e + f + g = h
        \end{equation}
    This is \ref{1.1}
    This is \ref{1.2}
    This is \ref{next}
    
\end{document}
```